# target row and column with select name

Tags: css

I have a form and am having a problem trying to style it.

Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

I need it to look like this:

[image]

I need to style the first row and column for the Title and the 2nd row 3rd column for to date of birth.

I'm having trouble targeting the correct selector/element. Here is what the html looks like:

```
<h6 class="title">Personal Information</h6>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <select name="title"></select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" id="firstname" 
            maxlength="50" size="50" class="" placeholder="First name*" 
            style="background-image:    url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,
            iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0I
            Ars4c6QAAAfBJREFUWAntVk1OwkAUZkoDKza4Utm61iP0AqyIDXahN2
            BjwiHYGU+gizap4QDuegWN7lyCbMSlCQjU7yO0TOlAi6GwgJc0fT/fz
            Pfmzet0crmD7HsFBAvQbrcrw+Gw5fu+AfOYvgylJ4TwCoVCs1ardYTr
            uqfj8fgV5OUMSVVT93VdP9dAzpVvm5wJHZFbg2LQ2pEYOlZ/oiDvwNc
            sFoseY4PBwMCrhaeCJyKWZU37KOJcYdi27QdhcuuBIb073BvTNL8ln4
            NeeR6NRi/wxZKQcGurQs5oNhqLshzVTMBewW/LMU3TTNlO0ieTiStjY
            hUIyi6DAp0xbEdgTt+LE0aCKQw24U4llsCs4ZRJrYopB6RwqnpA1YQ5
            NGFZ1YQ41Z5S8IQQdP5laEBRJcD4Vj5DEsW2gE6s6g3d/YP/g+BDnT7
            GNi2qCjTwGd6riBzHaaCEd3Js01vwCPIbmWBRx1nwAN/1ov+/drgFWI
            lfKpVukyYihtgkXNp4mABK+1GtVr+SBhJDbBIubVw+Cd/TDgKO2DPiN
            3YUo6y/nDCNEIsqTKH1en2tcwA9FKEItyDi3aIh8Gl1sRrVnSDzNFDJ
            T1bAy5xpOYGn5fP5JuL95ZjMIn1ya7j5dPGfv0A5eAnpZUY3n5jXcoe
            c5J67D9q+VuAPM47D3XaSeL4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=&quot;); 
            background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: 
            scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; 
            background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">                           
            <!--<input type="text" placeholder="First name*">-->
            <div class="form_error"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="Last name*">-->
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" id="lastname" 
                maxlength="50" size="50" placeholder="Last name*">
            <div class="form_error"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="Last name*">-->
            <input type="text" name="dob" value="" id="dob" maxlength="50" 
                size="50" placeholder="Date of birth (DD/MM/YYYY)*">
            <div class="form_error"></div>
            <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Date of birth (DD/MM/YYYY)*" class="dob">-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type="text" name="mobile" value="" id="mobile" 
                maxlength="50" size="50" placeholder="Mobile*">
            <div class="form_error"></div>
            <!--<input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile*">-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type="email" name="email" value="" id="email" 
                maxlength="50" size="50" placeholder="Email*">
            <div class="form_error"></div>
            <!--<input type="email" placeholder="Email*">-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type="text" name="emailconf" value="" id="emailconf" 
                maxlength="50" size="50" placeholder="Confirm Email*">
            <div class="form_error"></div>
            <!--<input type="email" placeholder="Confirm Email*">-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <input type="text" name="address1" value="" id="address1" 
                maxlength="50" size="50" placeholder="Address*">
            <div class="form_error"></div>
            <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Address*">-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type="text" name="suburb" value="" id="suburb" 
                maxlength="50" size="50" placeholder="Suburb*">
            <div class="form_error"></div>
            <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Suburb*">-->
        </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <select name="stateid">
        </select>                        
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="text" name="postcode" value="" id="postcode" 
            maxlength="4" size="10" placeholder="Postcode*">
        <div class="form_error"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like this. And bootstrap is responsive so You could see how it look on the expand view.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2><p class="text-center">Personal Information</p></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
          <option value="ms">Ms.</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First name *">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name *">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" id="mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile *">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="email" id="emailconf" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Email *">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" id="address1" class="form-control" placeholder="Address *">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" id="suburb" class="form-control" placeholder="Suburb *">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option class="collapse" value="mr">Info</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" id="postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Post Code *">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to make the structure better I would say load bootstrap CSS

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and use this markup:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="title">Personal Information</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select>
                <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
                <option value="mrs">Mrs.</option>
                <option value="ms">Ms.</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="date">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Confirm Email">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Address">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Suburb">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select>
                <option value="mr">NSW</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and you can customize the look of the form fields, just put this code after you load the Bootstrap

```
input, select { width:100%; padding:14px; margin:10px 0; border:2px solid #6aa295; }
```